# validation with tensorflow dataset and keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have two datasets

```
dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((x_train, mask_train), y_train))
dataset_dev   = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((x_dev, mask_dev), y_dev))
```

and a keras model

```
model = tf.keras.Model(...)
```

I would like to fit the `model` on the `dataset_train` and validate it on `dataset_dev`.

```
model.compile('adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=dataset_train, 
          epochs=args.epoch_num, 
          steps_per_epoch=1, 
          validation_data=dataset_dev,
          validation_steps=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: ('Error when checking model input: expected no data, but got:', (<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:0' shape=(?, 512, 64, 12) dtype=float64>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:1' shape=(?, 512, 64, 1) dtype=float64>))
```

But when I remove the validation data, things work

```
model.fit(x=dataset_train, 
          epochs=args.epoch_num, 
          steps_per_epoch=1)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are the shapes of your training and validation set? Because from the error it seems like you might be having different shapes ((None, 512, 64, 12) and (None, 512, 64, 1))

Comment: The shapes of train and validation sets are the same. The error is referring to the input tuple `(x_dev, mask_dev)` which has the shape of `((None, 512, 64, 12) and (None, 512, 64, 1))`.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21729